# How can I center GoogleMaps without rotating the map?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm using Xcode with Swift 4.

In the example I turn the map upside down (north facing down), then I press a button to center the map to a specific location. But when I do that, the map is turned back automatically (with north facing up).

Is there a way to center GoogleMaps to a position without rotating the map?

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.animate(toBearing: 180)
    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 1.1111, longitude: 1.1111, zoom: 1)
        mapView.camera = camera
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow documentation of Apple

rotateEnabled A Boolean value indicating whether the map camera’s heading information is used.

@property(nonatomic, getter=isRotateEnabled) BOOL rotateEnabled Discussion When this property is set to YES and a valid camera is associated with the map, the camera’s heading angle is used to rotate the plane of the map around its center point. When this property is set to NO, the camera’s heading angle is ignored and the map is always oriented so that true north is situated at the top of the map view.

When you press button to turn it upside down then change 
isRotateEnabled to no and then center the map it might help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer by myself, here is the code that can move the map without rotate it.

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 1.1111, longitude: 1.1111, zoom: mapView.camera.zoom, bearing: mapView.camera.bearing, viewingAngle: 0)
    mapView.camera = camera
}
```